# What does working_dir tag mean in a docker-compose yml file

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

Just wondering what the working_dir file really does for an image being loaded via docker-compose. A sample docker-compose.yml file as follows:

```
dev:
    extends:
        file: common.yml
        service: workspace
    volumes:
        - $ATOMSPACE_SOURCE_DIR:/atomspace
        - $COGUTILS_SOURCE_DIR:/cogutils
        # Uncomment the following lines if you want to work on moses
        # - $MOSES_SOURCE_DIR:/moses
    working_dir: /opencog # This is the same as the volume mount point below
    links:
        - postgres:db
        - relex:relex

postgres:
    image: opencog/postgres
    # Uncomment the following lines if you want to work on a production
    # system.
    # NOTE: The environment variable `PROD` is set `True` then the entrypoint
    # script in opencog/postgres does additional configurations.
    # environment:
    #     - PROD=True

relex:
    image: opencog/relex
    command: /bin/sh -c "./opencog-server.sh"
```

Comment: Though there is `docker-compose.yml`, you still have `Dockerfile` for building the image, right?

Answer (score 29):

`working_dir` sets the working directory of the container that is created. It is the same as the `--workdir` flag to `docker run`.

Comment: is the content under working_dir persisted? I don't think so from my little experiments. Is it simply a matter of changing into a specific directory after starting the image?

Comment: Yes, all it does it change the directory. If the directory doesn't already exist, it will be created. It doesn't persist anything. You can use `volumes` to persist data.

Comment: Does that mean it's the same as / or overrides WORKDIR in dockerfile? or is it used only when a dockerfile is not provided and you instantiate directly off an image of docker hub in your docker-compose file?